# how to add outer layer to circular seekbar

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I want to **create a circular seekBar as shown in image**. I found [this project](https://github.com/VadimDev/android-seekbar-like-ipod-clickwheel) on github. Now i **want to add an outer layer(purple color) to seekbar which will draw on the outer side of seekbar**. and give the indication of length of song. like

[image]

if there is any third party library,or guide me how to add this component to ipod-clickwheel

**My Solution**

I think i should add two library one i have told you above and another [circular seekbar](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AndroidCircularSeekBar).And put them in layout as in describe image. And associate the inner seekbar change listener to the outer one. but it may increase size of project.

I know i can create custom component but i am not good at it.

Comment: My **hint**: You have the **source code** for both. My **advice**: **Combine them** and make one thing out of two.